# Pandas - join on first row after min. delta

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

I have the following 2 dataframes

```
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'val':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'time':[10, 15, 17, 18]})
   time val
0    10   A
1    15   B
2    17   C
3    18   D

y = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'val':['x', 'y', 'z', 't'], 'time':[11, 12.1, 16, 22]})
   time val
0  11.0   x
1  12.1   y
2  16.0   z
3  22.0   t
```

I want to join each row in x to the first row in y that happens at least 2 seconds later:

```
  time_x  val_x  time_y  val_y
0    10    A      12.1    y
1    15    B      22.0    t 
2    17    C      22.0    t 
3    18    D      22.0    t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably slow on a big data frame but you can use apply to create a new column on x and join on that column:

```
x['ytime']=x.time.apply(lambda i: y.time[y.time>=i+2].min())
   time val  ytime
0    10   A   12.1
1    15   B   22.0
2    17   C   22.0
3    18   D   22.0

x.merge(y, how='left', left_on='ytime', right_on='time').drop('ytime', axis=1)
       time_x val_x  time_y val_y
0      10     A    12.1     y
1      15     B    22.0     t
2      17     C    22.0     t
3      18     D    22.0     t
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. One slight concern: does your solution depend at all on x and y having same lengths, or their indices being comparable?

Comment: Nope, not at all. The indexes can be completely arbitrary, and each data frame can be of any length, even 0. Only x.time and y.time have to be comparable. The only thing I would watch out for is if there isn't a next biggest value in y, in which case everything will still complete without error but the values in the resulting data frame will be NaN.